# Querying for Model Where No Events Exist During Selected Time Period

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Considering the model `Property` which `has_many :property_events`. `PropertyEvent` has a `start_date` and an `end_date` as a date.

I am interested in querying for vacancies or for all properties that do NOT have PropertyEvent within a selected time period.

I tried the following, but the first `PropertyEvent` that exists within the time period invalidates all properties from being returned.

```rb
@properties.where('NOT EXISTS (:property_event)',
   property_event: PropertyEvent.where("property_events.start_date <= ?",end_date).
                                 where("property_events.end_date >= ?",start_date)
)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
@properties.where(
  "NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM property_events pe
    WHERE (pe.start_date, pe.end_date) OVERLAPS (?, ?)
  )",
  start_date,
  end_date
)
```